# Replacing a 'Teaser'-themed node in a View its it's 'Full Content'-theme using ajax in Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, views

So, basicly, I have a Drupal 7 view that's displaying Teasers of Nodes.

WHen a user clicks this teaser, I want the node to load it's "Full Content"-content instead, and I would like this to be done using Ajax.

I've looked around a lot but I can only find solutions for Drupal 6, and many good solutions at that, but I'd love some help with figuring this out in D7!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [jQuery load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$('#teaser').load('node/exampleid #node-container');
```

Replace your teaser data with full-text.

The second method is to load hidden full-text with teaser in view; then, via jQuery on click method, just replace teaser by hidden-text.